# Ext Js Grid Column

Tags: extjs4

My grid needs to have 2 columns and second column needs to have a progress bar , status of progress bar and also radio buttons. How do we achieve this in Extjs.

Should this be a component column or a widget column.

I also need to handle json events so that I can change the progress of the progress bar and also set the radio buttons.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the widget grid in the Kitchen Sink examples:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#widget-grid

You can always bind your progress bar to a viewmodel data value or formula and update it with an interval or web socket.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The example is binding just progress bar. I need to radio buttons below that. and radio buttons to bind to a different property.

Comment: Try putting a 'Panel' as your widget then putting whatever you need such as your progress bar and two radio buttons inside of that panel just as you would if they stood alone.

Comment: Thanks...yes i do have have a grid column as a widget column, which has a panel and panel has a progress bar widget and radio button container. the radio button container has 4 radio buttons.Now i have to bind data to progress bar and radio buttons onload and also ajax callback after every 20 sseconds. I am not able to access the widget children (radio buttons and progress bar) in afterrender or renderer ...

Comment: I think the better way to go here would be to bind it: 
   bind: '{record.progress}  I think accessing it is possible but for ease of development, readability, etc... binding is simpler.  Make sure you are binding each of the children to a property on the record.
  {record.radio1value}